# create local variables debugging electron app in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I followed these instructions for debugging an electron app in VSCode.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Electron

I'm trying to debug the `renderer.js` file. The renderer only config doesn't work (times out) but the `"Electron: All"` option works.

Having only dabbled in javascript before, this is where I'm not sure if what I'm asking is possible or not. At this point I'd like to create local variables at the debug point. So for example, I'm following something online that looks like this:

```
const files = [...document.getElementById('filePicker').files]
```

Curious as to what the html5 file chooser looks like, I'd like to do something like this in the debug console:

```
const wtf = document.getElementById('filePicker').files
```

However this yields `undefined`. Note the goal would be to then interrogate `wtf` further with subsequent lines of code.

If I then highlight working code (the next few lines), and `debug evaluate` them, I also get `undefined`, even though they work if I step over them in the debugger. Those lines are:

```
const filesFormatted = files.map(({ name, path: pathName }) => ({
  name,
  pathName
}))
```

I'd like to be able to essentially write new code while debugging. Is this possible, either with VSCode or with some alternative setup? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Interestingly, removing the variable declaration seems to work, i.e. `wtf = document.getElementById('filePicker').files` (no `var wtf` or `const wtf`) The evaluation of future lines with definitions still doesn't work. I'm still not sure if I'm seeing a bug or a feature ...

Comment: Other testing seems to indicate that while `var wtf` such as `var wtf = 4` yields undefined, the value can actually be retrieved. However the use of `let` or `const` does not work. Why?